# Re-sort a LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, linkedhashset

Is there a method to sort the links in a `LinkedHashSet`? I know it preserves order in which the elements were added, but is there a way to re-sort those links as if it were a linked list, and have it still exhibit `HashMap` behaviors?

Comment: Do you really need a LinkedHashMap or would a TreeMap do? It is sorted, but doesn't retain insertion order.

Comment: Oh, you are talking about both maps and sets. Which one do you need?

Comment: @Axel yes but isn't a TreeMap log(n) to search? I don't want to make additions once created, so there is no need to maintain ordering, just to order it once.

Comment: I have to say that I don't fully get your requirement. But if you want a sorted map with O(1) lookup, you can create a TreeMap first and then use it to fill a LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, since `sort()` comes from `List` interface, which is not implemented by `LinkedHashSet`. It implements Set -> Collection interfaces.

But, there is a workaround, you can put data to ArrayList or LinkedList, sort it there and then put them to `LinkedHashSet` but now order will be sorted. Example:

```
ArraysList<> list = ..<put_your_data_here>..
list.sort(...); // with comparator
Set<> set = new LinkedHashSet(list);
```

As a result, you will have fully sorted `LinkedHashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in few ways.Sharing few which you can use

**Way 1:** Convert LinkedHashSet to TreeSet for natural-ordering

Steps:

- Create new LinkedHashSet object
- Store/add contents to LinkedHashSet
- Create new TreeSet object,
- Pass LinkedHashSet contents as argument to TreeSet’ inter-conversion constructor

```
package in.cj.resources.collection;

import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class SortingLinkedHashSetUsingTreeSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // creating LinkedHashSet object of type String
        LinkedHashSet<String> lhsCompanies = 
                new LinkedHashSet<String>();

        // adding elements to LinkedHashSet object
        lhsCompanies.add("Dutchview");
        lhsCompanies.add("Oracle");
        lhsCompanies.add("Microsoft");

        // Iterating using enhanced for-loop
        System.out.println("Insertion Order:"
                + " Iterating LinkedHashSet\n");
        for(String company : lhsCompanies) {
            System.out.println(company);
        }

        // convert LinkedHashSet to TreeSet
        TreeSet<String> tSet = new TreeSet<String>(lhsCompanies); 

        // Iterating using enhanced for-loop
        System.out.println("\n\nAscending sorting-order:"
                + " Iterating TreeSet\n");
        for(String company : tSet) {
            System.out.println(company);
        }
    }
}
```

**Way 2:** Convert LinkedHashSet to TreeSet for reverse-ordering

Steps:

- Create new LinkedHashSet object Store/add contents to LinkedHashSet
- Create new TreeSet object and provide reverse-order sorting-logic
  using Comparator Add LinkedHashSet contents  to TreeSet using
  addAll() method

```
package in.cj.resources.collection;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class ReverseSortingLinkedHashSetUsingTreeSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // creating LinkedHashSet object of type String
        LinkedHashSet<String> lhsCompanies = 
                new LinkedHashSet<String>();

        // adding elements to LinkedHashSet object
        lhsCompanies.add("Dutchview");
        lhsCompanies.add("Amazon");
        lhsCompanies.add("Google");

        // Iterating using enhanced for-loop
        System.out.println("Insertion Order:"
                + " Iterating LinkedHashSet\n");
        for(String company : lhsCompanies) {
            System.out.println(company);
        }

        // create new TreeSet object and provide reverse-sorting logic
        TreeSet<String> tSet = new TreeSet<String>(
                new Comparator<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
                        return str2.compareTo(str1);
                    }
                }); 

        // add LinkedHashSet to TreeSet for reverse-sorting elements
        tSet.addAll(lhsCompanies);

        // Iterating using enhanced for-loop
        System.out.println("\n\nDescending sorting-order:"
                + " Iterating TreeSet\n");
        for(String company : tSet) {
            System.out.println(company);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you really need to update an ordering of an existing `LinkedHashSet` and can't create a new ordered one, you could create a ordered copy of the data, clear the original set, then add all the elements.

```java
TreeSet<String> sortedCopy = new TreeSet<>(linkedHashSet);
linkedHashSet.clear();
linkedHashSet.addAll(sortedCopy);
```